# ERROR in The target entry-point "@spartacus/storefront" has missing dependencies: - angular-oauth2-oidc

Tags: spartacus-storefront

[image]

Hi Guys
I am getting bellow error while running "yarn start". I just upgraded to spartacus 3.0 from 2.1.
everything went well but in the end I am getting this error. can you please help me out

thanks in Advance !

---

Anuj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you also installed the `angular-oauth2-oidc` (^10.0.1 version) library when migrating to 3.0?

That was mentioned in migration docs: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/technical-changes-version-3/#auth-module-refactor